# Why did Hank Hill call his dog Lady Bird?

Tags: king-of-the-hill

I know that Hank Hill named his dog after Lady Bird Johnson, but why would he do that given that he's a staunch conservative Republican?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the show's wikia explains](http://kingofthehill.wikia.com/wiki/Lady_Bird):

> Lady Bird is named after the wife of former President Lyndon B.
>   Johnson. Lady Bird was a nickname by which she was commonly referred.
>   **Hank has a particular affinity to Lyndon Johnson as both are from
>   Texas.**